# ArrayList не клонируется

Tags: java, arraylist

Здравствуйте,

Пытаюсь клонировать `ArrayList` со всеми переменными. В итоге изменяю значения градусов в новом листе. И автоматически изменяются данные в старом листе. Хотя использую пример, в котором данные старого листа должны остаться неизменными.

```
ArrayList<HeatSensor> celsius = new ArrayList<HeatSensor>();
ArrayList<HeatSensor> fareng = (ArrayList<HeatSensor>) celsius.clone();

for(HeatSensor h: fareng) { 
    double far = h.getCelsius();
    far = 9*far/5 + 32;

    h.setCelsius(far);

    System.out.println(h.toString());
}
```

Чтобы было понятнее, вот что выводится на экран:

```
================celsius============================  
Heat : 70.0, 1/02/2017  
Heat : 30.0, 1/02/2017  
Heat : 35.0, 3/02/2017  

================fahrenheit==========================  
Heat : 158.0, 1/02/2017  
Heat : 86.0, 1/02/2017  
Heat : 95.0, 3/02/2017  

================celsius============================    
Heat : 158.0, 1/02/2017   
Heat : 86.0, 1/02/2017    
Heat : 95.0, 3/02/2017
```

Так же имеется другой вопрос относительно этой же программы.
[найти максимальное значение в ArrayList](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626339/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-arraylist)

Comment: хорошо. так и сделаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `clone` определен в `ArrayList` как копирование ссылок элементов.

```
public Object clone() {
    try {
        ArrayList<?> v = (ArrayList<?>) super.clone();
        v.elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
        v.modCount = 0;
        return v;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
        throw new InternalError(e);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, элементы равны с точностью до ссылки `celsius.get(i) == fareng.get(i)` для любого `i`, и при изменении элемента в одном списке вы измените его же в другом списке.

Для решения вашего вопроса нужно воспользоваться *глубоким копированием*, то есть сделать дополнительно и копии самих элементов.

```
for (HeatSensor h : celsius) {
    fareng.add(h.clone());
}
```

P.S. в разработке не рекомендуется использовать метод `clone`. Он считается плохим дизайном в приложении. Вам стоит воспользоваться копированием через конструктор.

```
List<HeatSensor> fareng = new ArrayList<>(celsius.size());
for (HeatSensor h : celsius) {
     fareng.add(new HeatSensor(h));
}
```

И сам конструктор:

```
public HeatSensor(HeatSensor another) {
     this.celsius = another.celsius; // и так далее по аналогии
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!

Answer (score 2):

Реализуйте метод `clone()` в классе `HeatSensor` и клонируйте списки следующим образом:

```
ArrayList<HeatSensor> celsius = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<HeatSensor> fareng = new ArrayList<>();
for (HeatSensor h : celsius)
        fareng.add(h.clone());
```

Ваш вариант не работает, т.к. клонируются списки, но объекты остаются одни и те же.

Comment: Спасибо большое!