# найти максимальное значение в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

`ArrayList` состоит из объектов, каждый из которых имеет температуру и время.
Необходимо найти максимальное значение температуры за каждый день.
Пока получается найти просто максимальное значение температуры следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 1; i < history.size(); i++) {
     if (history.get(0).getCelsius() > max &&
                  history.get(0).getDate().equals(history.get(i).getDate())) {
          max = history.get(0).getCelsius();
     }
}
```

Пытаюсь придумать как это лучше написать, но ничего не получается. Может быть есть какие-нибудь подсказки/наводки. Понимаю, что надо определить, что `history.get(i).getDate()` не должно равняться `history.get(i).getDate()` с таким же значением, но как это сделать, не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
histories
        .stream()
        .collect(
           //группируем по дате, отбрасывая время
           Collectors.groupingBy(e -> DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(e.getDate()),
                  //выбираем максимальный элемент на основе температуры
                  Collectors.maxBy((e1, e2) -> (int) (e1.getCelsius() - e2.getCelsius()))))
         //выводим результат
         .forEach((date, history) -> 
               System.out.println(date + " - " + history.map(History::getCelsius).get()));
```

где :

```
List<History> histories = new ArrayList<>();
```

А `History` имеет следующую структуру:

```
@Data
private static class History {
    LocalDateTime date;
    double celsius;
}
```

Comment: работает супер! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Создайте `Hashmap`, где ключем будет день, а значением максимальный градус. В каждой итерации вы ищете, есть ли в мапе этот день, если нет - добавляете и день и градус. Если же день уже был в мапе, просто сравниваете значения градусов и если нужно перезатираете

Comment: Сейчас попробую изучить. тогде мне надо будет конвертировать `arraylist` в `hashmap`

Comment: @Alex не надо конвертировать. создайте отдельно Map. потом двигайтесь по вашему списку и добавляйте в Map.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве альтернативного решения на Java 8:

```
Map<Date, Double> result = history.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(HeatSensor::getDate, HeatSensor::getCelsius, (a, b) -> a == null ? b : Math.max(a, b)));
```